# Encrypt with openssl and decrypt on iPhone with AES 128, ecb mode

Tags: iphone, cocoa, encryption, aes

**Update :** found the solution. I will update this question soon with the actual working code and command.

---

A client is encrypting a file server-side with C++, and I need to decrypt it in an iPhone application.

My client can crypt and decrypt on his side, and so do I on the iPhone, but we can't decrypt the file encrypted by each other.
I saw many related questions on SO, but none could help me find an implementation that works the same way on both side.

I want to output some sample values that we will accept as the common implementation.

I tried to crypt a file with openssl and decrypt it with cocoa, but couldn't.

Here is what I use for encryption:

`echo "123456789ABCDEFG" | openssl enc -aes-128-ecb -nosalt -K "41414141414141414141414141414141" -iv 0 > hello.txt.bin`

Adding the option -p to openssl call shows that the expected key and iv are used:

```
key=41414141414141414141414141414141
iv =00000000000000000000000000000000
```

And for cocoa decryption (in an NSData category):

```
- (NSData *)AESDecryptWithKey:(NSString *)key {

    char keyPtr[kCCKeySizeAES128+1]; // room for terminator (unused)
    bzero(keyPtr, sizeof(keyPtr)); // fill with zeroes (for padding)

    // fetch key data
    [key getCString:keyPtr maxLength:sizeof(keyPtr) encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSUInteger dataLength = [self length];

    //See the doc: For block ciphers, the output size will always be less than or 
    //equal to the input size plus the size of one block.
    //That's why we need to add the size of one block here
    size_t bufferSize = dataLength + kCCBlockSizeAES128;
    void *buffer = malloc(bufferSize);

    size_t numBytesEncrypted = 0;

    char iv[32];
    for (int i = 0; i < 32; i++) {
        iv[i] = 0;
    }

    CCCryptorStatus cryptStatus = CCCrypt(kCCDecrypt, kCCAlgorithmAES128, kCCOptionECBMode + kCCOptionPKCS7Padding,
                                          keyPtr, kCCKeySizeAES128,
                                          iv, //"00000000000000000000000000000000" /* initialization vector (optional) */,
                                          [self bytes], dataLength, /* input */
                                          buffer, bufferSize, /* output */
                                          &numBytesEncrypted);

    if (cryptStatus == kCCSuccess) {
        //the returned NSData takes ownership of the buffer and will free it on deallocation
        return [NSData dataWithBytesNoCopy:buffer length:numBytesEncrypted];
    }

    free(buffer); //free the buffer;
    return nil;
}
```

called this way:

```
- (void)testBinaryFileDecryption {
    NSString *databasePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"hello" ofType:@"txt.bin"];

    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:databasePath];
    NSAssert(nil != data, @"Encrypted data, freshly loaded from file should not be nil");

    NSData *plain = [data AESDecryptWithKey:@"AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA"];
    NSAssert(nil != plain, @"Decrypted plain data should not be nil");

    NSLog(@"Result: '%@'", [[NSString alloc] initWithData:plain encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]);
}
```

Result logs:
`Result: '4¨µ¢Ä½Pk£N`

What option am I forgetting? Is the encoding of the NSData returned something else than NSASCIIStringEncoding ?

Comment: What happened to the solution you found? Is there any chance you can post it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know nothing of iPhone development, but looking at this code, it appears you're trying to use the ascii-of-hex-encoding of the actual key to decrypt the packet. OpenSSL's enc requires the hex encoding because it converts the hex into bytes. Your *actual* key looks more like this, when converted directly to ascii.

> ```
> ["\037", " ", "!", "\"", "#", "$", "%", "&", "'", "\036", "\037", " ", "!", "\"", "#", "$"]
> ```

(All that might be obtuse. If you were to encode the string you're using for decrypting into the same format that OpenSSL enc accepts, the key would be `3331333233333334333533363337333833393330333133323333333433353336`.)

Try using a key specification of `41414141414141414141414141414141` to OpenSSL and use `AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA` in your iPhone code.

Also, I strongly suggest your initial tests be made with data that is exactly N*16 bytes long. OpenSSL enc uses PKCS#5 padding (unless you use `-nopad`), and your iPhone code is using PKCS#7 padding. On a cursory glance at RFCs, they seem to be the same padding mechanism, but I could be wrong.

And I know you're just trying things out here, but in real production code, please do not use [ECB mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_modes_of_operation#Electronic_codebook_.28ECB.29).

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.
With `echo "123456789ABCDEFG" | openssl enc -aes-128-ecb -nosalt -K "41414141414141414141414141414141" -iv 0  > hello.txt.bin` and ` NSData *plain = [data AESDecryptWithKey:@"AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA"];`, I get no useful result (Result: 'ÛÊÐÅp:wíö¹X+3u|Ýç;Q')

Comment: @Guillaume, I'm afraid I was too tired last night when writing my answer -- it appears that the same thing is happening with the IV as well: OpenSSL enc is using an IV of all-zeros, and your iPhone is using an IV of all ascii-zeros. (Bytes that look like 0x303030303030..) You can either pass an array of zeros to the CCCrypt routine, or you can pass a matching IV to OpenSSL enc.

Comment: I updated the code and the use of openssl command in the question.
Doesn't work either :(
Thanks for your tenacity. Any other idea?

Comment: @Guillaume, sorry, I'm at a complete loss. :(

Comment: Thank you to have tried. I hope someone will find what's wrong. It's not possible that I'm the first one to want this.

Answer (score 2):

I'm using Crypt::OpenSSL::AES to encrypt files that are decrypted in my iOS app, which decrypts using CommonCryptor.

```
    cryptStatus = CCCrypt(kCCDecrypt, kCCAlgorithmAES128, 0,
                          keyPtr, kCCKeySizeAES256,
                          IVECTOR /* initialization vector (optional) -- was NULL*/,
                          [self bytes], dataLength, /* input */
                          buffer, bufferSize, /* output */
                          &numBytesDecrypted);
```

To initialize the IVECTOR I'm using bzero.

```
bzero(keyPtr, sizeof(keyPtr)); // fill with zeroes (for padding)
```

To encrypt under OpenSSL in perl I do this:

```
my $cipher = Crypt::CBC->new( -key    => $key,
                              -literal_key => 1,
                              -header => 'none',
                              -iv =>     '0000000000000000',
                              -cipher => 'Crypt::OpenSSL::AES' );
```

OpenSSL seems to accept the '0000000000000000' IV as the same thing as ASCII 0 (null) characters.  Seems plausible in retrospect, but it required a lot of hair pulling because every crypto failure looks like every other crypto failure: garbage out.